# Android - CardView becomes a diamond shape because radius too large

Tags: java, android, android-cardview

I'm using `android.widget.CardView` in my application.

[image: CardView in my device]

In my Android 11 device, when radius is larger than the View, it will automatically adjust to half the size of the View.(I don’t know which version this was adjusted)

[image: CardView in lower system version]

In the lower system version(I use Android 7.1 to test), CardView will turn into a diamond shape when the radius is larger than the View.

Anyone know why and how to solve? Thx

Comment: To me this has nothing to do with CardView, the problem in the screenshot seems related to your ImageView or similar where you show your author icon

Comment: Use any roudedImageview to make circle like `implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'` rather than CardView. Explore [Liberary Link](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView)

Comment: It works on most devices, actually the only device I've seen this behavior was Huawei Mate 9 running android 7 (I don't know what's wrong with Huawei and Xiamo they're always annoying -_-). I managed to fix that by setting the corner to half of the height in code

Answer (score 0):

Very often, the Glide library is used to load images. This library can help round the edges as follows

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load(url)
        .circleCrop()
        .into(imageView)
```

Make friends with this library and you will be happy. Not only does it help the image to take shape, but it also uses memory correctly https://github.com/bumptech/glide

P.S: In my opinion, using CardView is very limiting for you.

You could use as a root element for example a Constraint Layout and as a background use a rounded shape as you like (rectangle) and place your image inside the layout.

To hold the shape I often using the next attribute (an example is below):
app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:2".

In your case ratio must be 1:1 because it is circle not ellipse, then you can use
`app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1"` or `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"`

I'm not sure if this will work in CardView, but it works well in ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the common and most simple method to make the image get a circular border using card view in android in XML

first create a card view inside your XML and inside that create a image view with exactly 1dp less then the card view in both width and height and then try to adjust the cardCornerRadius as per your requirements, that's it it is as simple as that.

I'm using `androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` here.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="35dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rounded_profile_img"
                android:layout_width="69dp"
                android:layout_height="69dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Thank you hope y'll like it and it is helpful for everyone.